# External hard drive spins down using NTFS but not EXT4 (Raspbian)

Tags: linux, hard-drive, filesystems, mount

I have a new 2015/2016 model Seagate Expansion Desktop (STEB2000300) connected to a Raspberry Pi. I have set on the [drives firmware](http://www.seagate.com/au/en/support/downloads/item/drive-settings-master-dl/) (in Windows 7) so that it turns off automatically after a quick 3 mins. With the drive mounted in Raspbian as NTFS, with the following */etc/fstab* setting, it turns off as desired after 3 minutes.

```
UUID=the devices UUID       /mnt/usbhdd     ntfs-3g    defaults          0       0
```

Then using the same drive formatted as EXT4, the drive does not turn off automatically after 3 mins, and the hard drives LED continuously flashes as if something is constantly accessing it. The last time I tried I used the steps [here](http://fenidik.blogspot.com/2010/03/ext4-disable-journal.html) to set the drive up as EXT4 again with the drive not sleeping:

Formatted the only partition as EXT4

```
mkfs.ext4 /dev/sdX1 Ext4Label
```

Disabled journaling

```
tune2fs -O ^has_journal /dev/sdX1
```

Enable writeback mode

```
tune2fs -o journal_data_writeback /dev/sdX1
```

Required fsck

```
e2fsck -f /dev/sdX1
```

/etc/fstab

```
UUID=a-different-longer-UUID       /mnt/usbhdd    ext4       defaults,data=writeback,noatime,nodiratime          0       0
```

I tried using `sudo hdparm -y /dev/sdX1` to sleep the drive, it sounds like it turns off for a split second but resumes immediately with the LED blinking continuously. The only way I can get the drive to sleep is by unmounting it:

```
sudo umount /dev/sdX1
```

and the drive sleeps after 3 mins. I've also tried finding out what is accessing the drive with `sudo fuser -vam /dev/sdX1` but it doesn't show much, only:

```
                     USER        PID ACCESS COMMAND
/dev/sdb2:           root     kernel mount /mnt/usbhdd
```

What else is can I try? I would like to use EXT4 over NTFS for better performance in Raspbian.

Comment: Maybe this helps: https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=178121

Comment: Thank you for that! It worked for me, my hard drive now sleeps after the set time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks to [nsilent22](https://superuser.com/questions/1046113/external-hard-drive-spins-down-using-ntfs-but-not-ext4-raspbian#comment1464175_1046113) for directing me to a solution. Steps taken:

Unmount partition

```
sudo umount /dev/sdX1
```

Command to format to EXT4

```
sudo mkfs.ext4 -E lazy_itable_init=0,lazy_journal_init=0 /dev/sdX1
```

My /ect/fstab

```
UUID=a-different-longer-UUID       /mnt/usbhdd     ext4       defaults         0       0
```

Remount partition

```
sudo mount /dev/sdX1
```

External hard drive now sleeps after the set time in [Seagate Drive Settings](http://www.seagate.com/au/en/support/downloads/item/drive-settings-master-dl/).